# Why does `rm -f` work but `rm --force` give me an error on OSX

Tags: bash, macos, unix, terminal

I'm curious about the following. When using `rm --force` on OSX I get the following error.

```
rm: illegal option -- -
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
```

With `rm -f` I get no error, even though the flags should be similar. What's the explanation behind this?

Comment: run `man rm` and see if `--force` option is there

Comment: It's not there, indeed just `-f`. Would you know why this is? Should I expect differences on different machines with such basic commands?

Comment: @kapser You should expect *basic features* of basic commands to be consistent. But while `rm` is about as ancient and basic as unix commands come, `--force` is a nonstandard GNU addition which you may not find in other implementations of `rm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the manpage](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rm.1.html), `rm` does not support any *longopts*, so you can only use `-f` and not `--force`.

This is probably due to its BSD heritage, as opposed to a GNU/Linux heritage.

I cannot ever imagine typing `rm --force` anyway, as `rm -f` and `rm -rf` are too much ingrained.